# get qty of products in an order with several products

Tags: magento

Hi i would like to know how to get the qty_ordered of a specific product in an order with several products.

i have tried these

```
     $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->
        addAttributeToSelect('shipping_description')->
        addAttributeToSelect('increment_id')->
        addAttributeToSelect('base_grand_total')->
        addAttributeToSelect('total_qty_ordered')->
        addAttributeToSelect('shipping_address_id')->
        addAttributeToSelect('billing_address_id')->
        addAttributeToSelect('created_at')->
        addAttributeToSelect('shipping_incl_tax')->
        addAttributeToFilter('status', 'pending');
```

but    addAttributeToSelect('total_qty_ordered')-> which total? which product?

Answer (score 5):

"total_qty_ordered"  give total no orders qty of all product in an order

If,you want item qty of product then

you  can try

```
  <?php $order_id = 2314; //use your own order id 
$order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($order_id); //load order by order id 
    $ordered_items = $order->getAllItems();
    foreach($ordered_items as $item){     //item detail 
        echo $item->getItemId();
     //product id     
    echo $item->getSku();    
     echo $item->getQtyOrdered(); 
    //ordered qty of item    
     echo $item->getName();    
     // etc. 
    } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

for me it worked like this:

```
<?php 
    $_order = $this->getOrder(); //call the order
    $order_qty = floor($_order->getData('total_qty_ordered')); //get qty of all items rounded to full number (without 3.0000 or so)
    echo $order_qty;
?>
```

used it on *template/sales/order/totals.phtml*

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this also:-

```
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
$order_data = $orderCollection->getAllVisibleItems();
       foreach ($order_data as $key) {
            $id = $key->getProductId();

            $orderItems = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
                  ->addAttributeToFilter('product_id', $id);
                  foreach ($orderItems as $key ) {
                       echo $number_of_prod =  $key->getQtyOrdered();
                  }
        }
```